# How to have an activity that will run once only?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I show an alert dialog only on the first run of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409595/how-do-i-show-an-alert-dialog-only-on-the-first-run-of-my-application)

In my app there will be a Terms and Conditions activity which shows some conditions along with ok and cancel buttons, and when the user presses 'ok' button the app continue and go on running. Next time when the user starts this app the Terms and Conditions activity must not run as its already accepted before. How to get such a functionality in my app?

I don't want to use shared preferences or internal app memory. I want to customize the launch of intent between activities.

Comment: If you don't store that the user has seen the T&C somewhere how can you know next time?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use the shared preferences? This would be by far the easiest. Of course you can think of more complicated ways that don't use shared preferences, but you have to store it somewhere. Some messier ways:

- use a SQLite database
- use your own file format
- use a unique device id (careful, Android ID is not really unique) and store it on a remote server
- store it in a really crazy way, such as a special text message, or a contact, or ...
- find some way to change your application code (might be possible on a rooted phone?)

To summarize: SharedPreferences is made for this type of thing. It works. Use it. No really.