# Want to display a dialog only once after the app been installed

Tags: android

How can I make my dialog appear only once after my Android app is installed on the device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show an alert dialog only on the first run of my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409595/how-do-i-show-an-alert-dialog-only-on-the-first-run-of-my-application)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use SharedPreference to store the `firstrun` value, and check in your launching activity against that value. If the value is set, then no need to display the dialog. If else, display the dialog and save the `firstrun` flag in SharedPreference.

ex (in your launching activity):

```
public void onCreate(){
    boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
    if (firstrun){
        //... Display the dialog message here ...
        // Save the state
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `getSharedPreferences` with a S at the end