# Create a EditTextPreference Dialog Once on Launch

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-preferences

I know this is very simple, but it was never answered explicitly here: [Want to display a dialog only once after the app been installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879013/want-to-display-a-dialog-only-once-after-the-app-been-installed). Could someone give an example of the display the dialog call that I could make within my MainActivity class?

Specifically I need to check to see whether that value exists within a Parse Database. If it does, then allow the user to continue. Otherwise do not close out of the dialog box and wait for them to add a new username.

The XML would look something like this:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_user_profile" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="prefUsername"
        android:summary="@string/pref_user_name_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_user_name" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if *preferences* has returned "default," if so then show a dialog box and commit those values to the *preferences*.

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

String p = prefs.getString("prefUsername", "default");

    if (p.equals("default")) {
        createDialogBox();
        p = prefs.getString("prefUsername", "default");
    }


public void createDialogBox() 
        {

    final EditText et = new EditText(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please give Input");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Input")
            .setView(et)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    String c = et.getText().toString().trim();
                    editor.putString("prefsUsername", c);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well it was answered in that question!

> Use SharedPreference to store the firstrun value, and check in your launching activity against that value. If the value is set, then no need to display the dialog. If else, display the dialog and save the firstrun flag in SharedPreference.
>   ex (in your launching activity):

```
public void onCreate(){
boolean firstrun = getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
if (firstrun){
    ...Display the dialog
    // Save the state
    getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
        .commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I mean how to create a dialog box that only stores a value once (under the condition that it does not exist within a Parse database). See my updated question