# Playstore detailed reviews

Tags: android, google-play

Is there an api which would help me gather all the review information from playstore, given the app name? The requirement is to replicate a screen more or less similar to the Playstore "Detailed Review" screen(attached here for quick reference).

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused. Do you want to create a screen that has the layout of the screen you attached or do you want to be able to read the actual review and do something with them? If it is the latter, then there is no Play Store API unfortunately. It probably has to do with privacy issues, I think. If you want a screen that has the same layout, then I don't think you need to gather the review information.

I searched around and I found this: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

There is more information about the Play Store API here: [Is there a way to see that a user has submitted a review to the Android Marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690016/is-there-a-way-to-see-that-a-user-has-submitted-a-review-to-the-android-marketpl?rq=1)

Comment: It is not about creating a UI interface like the one I showed, but to get the data from a server using some api mechanism, as is stated in the second part of your answer. i have seen this api prior to posting this here.; but the mentioned api seem to have lots of known issues, which is why I thought of posting this here.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what to tell you. I know there isn't a Play Store API, so I doubt you can do what you want. Maybe somebody else knows of a workaround.